# Select a certain part of this string

Tags: regex

I need to select a small portion of a string.

Here's an example string: `http://itunes.apple.com/app/eyelashes/id564783832?uo=5`

I need: `564783832`

A couple of things to keep in mind:

- The number will always be preceded by `id` (ie. `id564783832`)
- There may or may not be a `?uo=5` following the number (and it could be other parameters besides `uo`)
- The string I need can be different lengths (won't always be 9 digits)
- The text preceding `id` will have similar formatting (same # of slashes, but text will be different)

This will ultimately be implemented with Ruby.

Comment: might there be other things preceded by id?

Comment: here is one: `(tool)?|(language)?|(yourcodes)?`

Comment: @Kent: Sorry, post updated. I'm using Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without knowing your language/tool, just assume look behind was supported.

```
'(?<=id)\d+'
```

Comment: You may want to check for the end as well, this may be possible - `itunes.apple.com/app/abcid1234/id12498761`

Comment: then I assume OP wants two numbers. (based on the Keep in mind list) :) The two numbers (following id) both match the criteria in that list.

Comment: **I** would guess that OP only wants the last one, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I just want one (that `564783832` number I mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```sh
awk '{print $2}' FS='(id|?)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match some sequence of digits preceded by "id" - this assumes that those are the only sequence of digits preceded by "id":

```
(?<=id)\d++
```

A test case in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "http://itunes.apple.com/app/eyelashes/id564783832?uo=5";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=id)\\d++");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output

```
564783832
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:

```
[\w\/]+id(\d+)(\?|$)
```